# Can not get mongoose virtual fields back in response

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the following schema with a few virtual fields. I am not able to get these virtuals back in the response:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Sportclub } from './sportclub.schema';
export type SportEventDocument = SportEvent & mongoose.Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } })
export class SportEvent {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  title: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  description: string;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: (value: number) => {
        // Check if the value is a positive number
        return value >= 0;
      },
      message: 'Price must be a positive number',
    },
  })
  price: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  startDateAndTime: Date;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: (value: number) => {
        // Check if the value is a positive number
        return value >= 0;
      },
      message: 'Duration must be a positive number',
    },
  })
  durationInMinutes: number;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    validate: {
      validator: (value: number) => {
        // Check if the value is a positive number greater than or equal to 1
        return value >= 1;
      },
      message:
        'Maximum number of participants must be a positive number greater than or equal to 1',
    },
  })
  maximumNumberOfParticipants: number;

  @Prop({
    required: false,
    default: [],
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'User',
  })
  enrolledParticipants: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId[];

  @Prop({ required: true })
  hostId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  sportclub: Sportclub;
}

export const SportEventSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SportEvent);

//virtuals
SportEventSchema.virtual('enrolledParticipantsCount').get(function () {
  return this.enrolledParticipants.length;
});

SportEventSchema.virtual('maximumIncome').get(function () {
  return this.maximumNumberOfParticipants * this.price;
});

SportEventSchema.virtual('currentIncome').get(function () {
  return this.enrolledParticipants.length * this.price;
});

SportEventSchema.virtual('isFull').get(function () {
  return this.enrolledParticipants.length >= this.maximumNumberOfParticipants;
});
```

I try to retrieve all sportevents in an api call with the use of this method:

```
  // get all sport events.
  async getAllSportEvents(): Promise<SportEvent[]> {
    console.log('get all sportevents service (api) called');
    try {
      const result: SportEvent[] = await this.sportEventModel
        .find()
        .lean({ virtuals: true });
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException(error.message, 400);
    }
  }
```

this is the interface for a SportEvent:

```
import { Sportclub } from './Sportclub';

export interface SportEvent {
  _id?: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  startDateAndTime: Date;
  durationInMinutes: number;
  maximumNumberOfParticipants: number;
  enrolledParticipants?: string[];
  hostId: string;
  sportclub: Sportclub;
  //virtuals
  enrolledParticipantsCount?: number;
  isFull?: boolean;
  maximumIncome?: number;
  currentIncome?: number;
}
```

The response does not contain the virtuals fields. I have no clue why it does not. Any one who knows?

Answer (score 1):

found the problem, this part: `.lean({ virtuals: true });` somehow still removes the virtuals. I just removed this line and now it works. If someone knows why, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The `lean()` method are returned a plain javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents. They have no save method, getters/setters, virtuals, or other Mongoose features. If you want to use virtuals with `lean`, please use this plugin: https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/lean-virtuals